# Prove that $\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty\,\dfrac{(-1)^r\,n}{r!\,(r+1)!}\,\prod\limits_{k=1}^r\,\left(n^2-k^2\right)=(-1)^{n+1}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

> If n is a positive integer, prove that:
>   $$\begin{align}n - {\frac{n(n^2-1^2)}{2!}}+{\frac{n(n^2-1^2)(n^2-2^2)}{2!3!}} + \ldots\phantom{aaaaaaaaaa} &&\\
> +(-1)^r{\frac{n(n^2-1^2)(n^2-2^2)\cdots(n^2-r^2)}{r!(r+1)!}}+\ldots &=& (-1)^{n+1}\end{align}$$

I tried by simplifying it to $\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{2}\binom{n+1}{1}+\binom{n}3\binom{n+2}{2}-\ldots$  , or $\sum(-1)^r\binom{n}{r+1}\binom{n+r}{r}$. But I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: You forgot the alternating sign in your simplified sums.

Comment: @Arthur oh yes, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(-1)^r{\frac{n(n^2-1^2)(n^2-2^2)...(n^2-r^2)}{r!(r+1)!}}=\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r)}{(r+1)!}\cdot\dfrac{-(n+1)\cdot-(n+2)\cdots-(n+r)}{r!}$$

Think of the coefficient of $x$ in $$(1+x)^n\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)^{-(n+1)}=\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1+x}$$

Comment: $\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1+x}$ will be $x^{n+1}(1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+...)$ ..all terms have power greater than $x^{n+1}$ .. I'm not sure how to find the coefficient of x  then..

Comment: @Rick, Divide $$x^{n+1}$$ by $x+1$

Answer (score 2):

The product is:

$$\prod (n^2-k^2)=(n-r)(n-r+1)\cdots(n-1)(n+1)\cdots(n+r-1)(n+r)$$
$$=\frac{(2r+1)!}{n}{n+r \choose 2r+1}$$
The $n$ is because we are missing that term, the binomial symbol is because we recognize a product of $2r+1$ going down from $n+r$, and the factorial is because the binomial symbol is missing its denominator.

You get

$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty (-1)^r\frac{(2r+1)!}{r!(r+1)!}{n+r \choose 2r+1}$$
Here you recognize another choose symbol
$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty (-1)^r{2r+1\choose r}{n+r \choose 2r+1}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} (-1)^r{2r+1\choose r}{n+r \choose 2r+1}$$
where the last term told us the largest reasonable value for $r$ (if bottom is larger than top, it's zero).

You already got to here. Now you can just calculate the recursion. Assuming you have term $a_n$, let's compute the next one:

$$a_{n+1}=\sum_{r=0}^{n} (-1)^r{2r+1\choose r}{n+1+r \choose 2r+1}$$
We use the summation property of the Pascal's triangle:
$$a_{n+1}=\sum_{r=0}^{n} (-1)^r{2r+1\choose r}\left({n+r \choose 2r+1}+{n+r \choose 2r}\right)$$
Can you continue expressing this with $a_n$?